# Any Hey-like email apps that are open source or otherwise available or in the works?

Tags: email, email-client, imap, email-attachments

[Hey App](https://hey.com/how-it-works/) provides a pretty interesting email solution. Nearly every function in Hey appears to be doable with software on top of IMAP and SMTP. Are there any such similar apps that are available or in the works that will give us this kind of functionality with Gmail via IMAP+SMTP or other stock email services such as cPanel provided solutions?